# What if i schedule tasks for celery to perform every minute and it is not able to complete it in time?

Tags: celery, scheduled-tasks, celery-task, celerybeat

If I schedule the task for every minute and if it is not able to be getting completed in the time(one minute). Would the task wait in queue and it will go on like this? if this happens then after few hours it will be overloaded. Is there any solution for this kind of problems?

I am using beat and worker combination for this. It is working fine for less records to perform tasks. but for large database, I think this could cause problem.

Comment: raise the worker concurrency, add more workers..

Comment: Okay but even if i start three workers, i have only one task. Can only one task be divided among workers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Task is assign to queue (RabbitMQ for example).

Workers are queue consumers, more workers (or worker with high concurrency) - more tasks could be handled in parallel.

Your periodic task produce messages of the same type (I guess) and your celery router route them to the same queue.
Just set your workers to consume messages from that queue and that's all.

```
celery worker -A celeryapp:app -l info -Q default -c 4 -n default_worker@%h -Ofair
```

In the example above I used `-c 4` for concurrency of four (eqv. to 4 consumers/workers). You can also start move workers and let them consume from the same queue with `-Q <queue_name>` (in my example it's `default` queue).

**EDIT:**
When using celery (the worker code) you are initiate `Celery` object. In `Celery` constructor you are setting your `broker` and `backend` (celery used them as part of the system)
for more info: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html#application

Comment: Okay and i guess rabbitmq and beat with redis do same things. Am i correct?

Comment: Do you mean rabbitmq as celery `broker` and redis as celery `backend`?
 you are talking about the configuration

Comment: I think i got confused. How do i use rabbitmq? I have used celery worker with celery beat and redis.